# How to change counter variable from a different class and show on kivy screen python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, kivy

Please Help me with this new problem.

I want to **increment** the variable **Num** of **ScreenOne Class** from different class **ScreenTwo** by it's Function **Increment**.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivmob import TestIds ,RewardedListenerInterface,AdMobRewardedVideoAdListener ,KivMob
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class ScreenOne(Screen):
    Num = NumericProperty(0)
    def Increase(self):
        ScreenTwo().Increase()

class ScreenTwo(ScreenOne):
    def Increase(self):
        ScreenOne.Num +=1

Builder.load_string("""
#.import MDRaisedButton kivymd.uix.button.MDRaisedButton
<Screen_Manager>:
    ScreenOne:

<ScreenOne>:
    name:"One"
    Label:
        text:"Number "+str(root.Num)
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.7}
    MDRaisedButton:
        text:"Click here"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.6}
        on_release:
            root.Increase()

""")

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return Screen_Manager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

This code gives me error

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'kivy.properties.NumericProperty' and 'int'
```

Please Find me a way to increment the Num variable from **class ScreenTwo**.
and the **condition is that it must show on Kivy Screen**

Any Help will be Appreciated.
Please Help !!

Comment: did you try `ScreenOne.Num = ScreenOne.Num + 1` ?

Comment: @furas yes I tried but didn't Work for me

Comment: I see two problems, (1) `ScreenOne.Num` is class item and you should rather use `self.Num`. (2) using `ScreenTwo().Increase()` you create new instance of `ScreenTwo` again and again and it sets `Num` to `0` again and again. You should create `ScreenTwo()` only once (ie. in `__init__`) and later use this only this one instances.

Comment: @furas Now I understand the real Problem.But I don't Know Where should I create the objects of these classes.Can I make them global and can use in in classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned `id` to `ScreenManager` and added this manager to every `Screen`

```
<Screen_Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    ScreenOne:
        id: one
        name: "One"
        manager: screen_manager
    ScreenTwo:
        id: two
        name:"Two"
        manager: screen_manager
```

This way I can access other window using `manager` and `id` of other screen.

```
class ScreenOne(Screen):
    Num = NumericProperty(0)
    def Increase(self):
        # change in current Screen - ScreenOne
        self.Num += 1
        print('One:', self.Num)

        # change in other Screen - ScreenTwo
        self.manager.ids.two.Num += 2
        print('Two:', self.manager.ids.two.Num)

        # or
        #self.manager.ids.two.Increase()
```

---

Full working code which changes `Num` in other screen and with buttons to see other screens.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
#from kivmob import TestIds, RewardedListenerInterface, AdMobRewardedVideoAdListener, KivMob
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    Num = NumericProperty(0)
    def Increase(self):
        # change in current Screen - ScreenOne
        self.Num += 1
        print('One:', self.Num)

        # change in other Screen - ScreenTwo
        #self.manager.ids.two.Num += 2
        #print('Two:', self.manager.ids.two.Num)

        # or
        self.manager.ids.two.Increase()

class ScreenTwo(ScreenOne):
    def Increase(self):
        # change in current Screen - ScreenTwo
        self.Num += 2
        print('Two:', self.Num)

Builder.load_string("""
#.import MDRaisedButton kivymd.uix.button.MDRaisedButton
<Screen_Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    ScreenOne:
        id: one
        name: "One"
        manager: screen_manager
    ScreenTwo:
        id: two
        name:"Two"
        manager: screen_manager

<ScreenOne>:
    Label:
        id: lb1
        text: "Number " + str(root.Num)
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.7}
    MDRaisedButton:
        text:"Click here"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.6}
        on_release:
            root.Increase()
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Go To Screen Two"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.1}
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'Two'

<ScreenTwo>:
    Label:
        id: lb2
        text: "Number " + str(root.Num)
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.7}
    MDRaisedButton:
        text:"Click here"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.6}
        on_release:
            root.Increase()
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Go To Screen One"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.1}
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'One'

""")

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return Screen_Manager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

---

**EDIT:** it seems you don't have to assign `screen_manager` to `manager` because it has already built-in `manager` (or you can use built-in `parent`)

```
    # using `id
    #self.parent.ids.two.Increase()
    self.manager.ids.two.Increase()

    # using `name`
    #self.parent.get_screen('Two').Increase()
    self.manager.get_screen('Two').Increase()
```

Using `id` you have to set ids in `Screen_Manager`, not in `Screen`

```
<Screen_Manager>:
    ScreenOne:
        id: one
    ScreenTwo:
        id: two
```

But using `name` you can set names in `Screen_Manager` or in `Screen`

---

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
#from kivmob import TestIds, RewardedListenerInterface, AdMobRewardedVideoAdListener, KivMob
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    Num = NumericProperty(0)
    def Increase(self):
        # change in current Screen - ScreenOne
        self.Num += 1
        print('One:', self.Num)

        # change in other Screen - ScreenTwo
        # using `id`
        #self.parent.ids.two.Num += 2
        #self.parent.ids.two.Increase()
        #self.manager.ids.two.Num += 2
        #self.manager.ids.two.Increase()    

        #print('Two:', self.manager.ids.two.Num)

        # using `name`
        #self.parent.get_screen('Two').Num += 2
        #self.parent.get_screen('Two').Increase()
        #self.manager.get_screen('Two').Num += 2
        self.manager.get_screen('Two').Increase()

class ScreenTwo(ScreenOne):
    def Increase(self):
        # change in current Screen - ScreenTwo
        self.Num += 2
        print('Two:', self.Num)

Builder.load_string("""
#.import MDRaisedButton kivymd.uix.button.MDRaisedButton
<Screen_Manager>:
    ScreenOne:
        id: one
    ScreenTwo:
        id: two

<ScreenOne>:
    name: "One"
    other: "Two"
    Label:
        id: lb1
        text: "Number " + str(root.Num)
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.7}
    MDRaisedButton:
        text:"Click here"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.6}
        on_release:
            root.Increase()
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Go To Screen " + root.other
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.1}
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = root.other

<ScreenTwo>:
    name: "Two"
    other: "One"
    Label:
        id: lb2
        text: "Number " + str(root.Num)
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.7}
    MDRaisedButton:
        text:"Click here"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.6}
        on_release:
            root.Increase()
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Go To Screen " + root.other
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.1}
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = root.other
""")

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return Screen_Manager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

---

**BTW:** you can use `manager` or `parent` to set some value(s) in `ScreenManager` and share it with all `Screens`.

---

**EDIT:**
Using inheritance

```
class ScreenTwo(ScreenOne):
```

was missleading.

if `ScreenTwo` is not a `Screen` then you can create it without inheritance

```
class ScreenTwo():
```

And create it in `ScreenOne.__init__`. And send `ScreenOne` (`self`) to `ScreenTwo` so `ScreenTwo` will have access to variables in `ScreenOne`

```
class ScreenOne(Screen):

    Num = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.second = ScreenTwo(self) # create instance of `ScreenTwo` and send `ScreenOne` (self) as argument

    def Increase(self):
        self.second.Increase()  # run `Increase()` from `ScreenTwo`

class ScreenTwo():
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.first = other  # keep access to `ScreenOne`

    def Increase(self):
        self.first.Num +=1  # change `Num` in `ScreanOne`
```

---

Full example

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
#from kivmob import TestIds, RewardedListenerInterface, AdMobRewardedVideoAdListener, KivMob
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ScreenOne(Screen):

    Num = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.second = ScreenTwo(self) # create instance of `ScreenTwo` and send `ScreenOne` (self) as argument

    def Increase(self):
        self.second.Increase()  # run `Increase()` from `ScreenTwo`

class ScreenTwo():
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.first = other  # keep access to `ScreenOne`

    def Increase(self):
        self.first.Num +=1  # change `Num` in `ScreanOne`


Builder.load_string("""
#.import MDRaisedButton kivymd.uix.button.MDRaisedButton
<Screen_Manager>:
    ScreenOne:

<ScreenOne>:
    name: "One"
    Label:
        id: lb1
        text: "Number " + str(root.Num)
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.7}
    MDRaisedButton:
        text:"Click here"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.6}
        on_release:
            root.Increase()
""")

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return Screen_Manager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much for Your such a kind Answer.But in My case **The ScreenTwo Class is not a Screen class or it is not a screen also**,So I can't use manager or parent in ScreenTwo class.It is a Normal Class in which there is a function **Increase()** which wants to change the num variable of **ScreenOne which is a Screen class**

Comment: can you please explain a way to change variable of any class from a different class

Comment: if it is normal class then why do you define it as `class ScreenTwo(ScreenOne):` ? it is useless and missleading. If you don't want it use as screen then why to inherit `ScreenTwo` from `ScreenOne`.

Comment: If you want to access variable or function from other class then first you have to create its instance - you can create it in `ScreenOne.__init__` - ie `self.second = ScreenTwo()` - and later use its instance `self.second.Increase()`. But if `ScreenTwo` has to change value from `ScreenOne` then you should send it as argumenet - ie. `self.second = ScreenTwo(self)` and assign it inside `ScreenTwo.__init__` to some variable - ie. `self.first = other` and use `self.first.Increase()`

Comment: Sorry for any misleading code written I am beginner.I inherit ScreenOne in ScreenTwo so that i think i can access variable Num of ScreenOne

Comment: Thank You So Much For Your Kind Help